# Email id starting with number is not accepted

Tags: objective-c, regex, email-validation

I am using following code for email validation . If email id start with number then it is not accepting , I want to accept that like **123a@asd.com** . please suggest me .

```
BOOL stricterFilter = NO; 
NSString *stricterFilterString = @"^[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$";
NSString *laxString = @"^.+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*$";
NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailID];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The strict regex says accept any of `A-Z` `0-9` `a-z` `.` `_` `%` `+` and `-` as items for the email address, which means it will accept a leading number for the email address - the code works as written. Now if there's leading **whitespace** or trailing **whitespace** then those will trigger a rejection for strict, and trailing **whitespace** will trigger a rejection for lax

Comment: **At future software developers**: Please do not blindly copy & paste an email regex that does not allow digits at the beginning of an email address. According to [RFC 3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696), `123a@asd.com` is a valid email address.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my observation, check may be you are adding white space that's why its not validating it properly - As @Petesh is also mentioning in the comments - Great explanation man.

```
-(BOOL)validate:(NSString *)emailID {
    BOOL stricterFilter = YES;
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"^[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$";
    NSString *laxString = @"^.+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*$";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailID];
}

-(void)validateEmails   {
    if ([self validate:@" 123a@asd.com"]   == true)    {
        NSLog(@"true");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"false"); //Result
    }

    if ([self validate:@"123a@asd.com"]   == true)    {
        NSLog(@"true"); //Result
    } else {
        NSLog(@"false");
    }

    if ([self validate:@"myemail@gmail.com"]   == true)    {
        NSLog(@"true"); //Result
    } else {
        NSLog(@"false");
    }

    if ([self validate:@"my?email@gmail.com"]   == true)    {
        NSLog(@"true");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"false"); //Result
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *mailreg=@"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *mailtest=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",mailreg];
[mailtest evaluateWithObject:checkString]
```

Try this